# Could anybody help me figure out how to undo a move in a chess game? (python)

Tags: python

I have created a Chess AI game but have become stuck on a specific problem. If I am playing against an AI and I want to undo my previous move, I am unable to do so and the AI just keeps picking another move. Here is my code:

```
if e.key == p.K_z: 
    GS.UndoMove() #Undo the last move
    MoveMade = True
    Animate = False #Don't animate the pieces returning to their previous positions
    GameOver = False #No player has won yet
    if AIThinking:
        MoveFinderProcess.terminate() #Stops the AI about thinking about potential moves as we don't know what move will be played next
        AIThinking = False
    MoveUndone = True
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

I tried changing some of the boolean variables, thinking that would fix it bt that didn't work.

Comment: Not knowing how the state of the game and the AI is managed, it is tricky to suggest a solution. Have you tried stopping the AI move *before* calling `GS.UndoMove()`?